# walk() efficiency inconsistent

Tags: python, os.walk, scandir

I'm working on an app that walks directories, so I've downloaded the lastest scandir module for Python 2.7.  I'm getting some very strange inconsistent speed results with walking, and I can't quite understand what is happening. Since my program has to do quite a few things with each directory before moving on, I want to make this as efficient as possible.

To test the module out I did a very simple script:

```
import os
src_dir = r'/'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(src_dir):
    print root
```

Scanning my entire root drive took roughly 1:30 after running it several times in a row. I then changed to code to:

```
import scandir as sd
src_dir = r'/'
for root, dirs, files in sd.walk(src_dir):
    print root
```

I ran this a few times and averaged about 0:50 every time.

There were a few directories on my system that contained about 10,000 symlinks each that would hold the script up for a few seconds per directory, which added about 15 seconds to the whole process.

Now I change back to os.Walk, and point to the parent dir of the folders containing all those symlinks, and it takes about 20-25 seconds on the first run, then if I run it again, it takes only 2 seconds for the entire process on each subsequent run. The same behavior happens with scandir.

All I can think of is there is some kind of cache on the filesystem level that the walk leaves behind and can access on subsequent executions, as long as I walk the same tree, and given the tree isn't too big.

I can consistently run a find command on the root in around 15 seconds, so it seems the Python walks start to really slow down with large trees. Any thoughts as to what may be going on here?

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com

Comment: Filesystem metadatata is heavily cached by the OS; when not yet cached you have to use *slow* I/O access to load the information from disk. If cached, you get fast access to the memory-stored info.